# sharepoint limit

Tags: managed-metadata, metadata, list-view-threshold, sharepoint-library, threshold

I have a templates library in SharePoint with around 80K items (while I know the threshold limit is 5K) - this library uses no folders, but just enterprise keywords and metadata - can anyone suggest if there's a better way in SharePoint of if this is going to cause issues at all?

Comment: You can use filters and indexing to manage large list.  Have a look at this: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Comment: Issue might come when you try to sync using onedrive .